# How can a manage user secrets for .Net MAUI app

Tags: azure-devops, maui, azure-releases

I am looking for a way to use secrets for a .Net MAUI app.
I need to be able to debug locally, but I cannot let secrets be stored in source control.

And in my Azure release pipeline, I need different secrets values to be used for different stages (dev and store).

I cannot find a solution for that so far. I did find a suggestion to store secrets in Key Vault and use Azure functions to retrieve them. But the secrets I have contain information my app needs to call my Azure functions. So here I see a vicious circle.

ADDED:

I tried this code to get my secrets from the key vault:

```
    IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

    configurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri("https://myvault.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
    configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
```

But this throws an exception:
Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException
Message=ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Confidential client and managed identity flows are not available on mobile platforms and on Mac.

Comment: Why do you need to use Azure functions? You can integrate an application directly with KeyVault or Azure App Configuration for storing runtime configuration values and secrets.

Comment: @DanielMann I saw it on Stack Overflow, and have no idea why.

Comment: @DanielMann Here is what I found: "You should not connect an app to a keyvault for the same reason an app should never talk to a remote database directly.

The credentials to connect to a keyvault/remote database MUST be stored on the device SOMEWHERE because the device makes the request. This means that the user could decompile your app, inspect their RAM or outgoing connections and steal the credentials. This would mean that they could then impersonate you."  This looks like a dead end...